# Property init in C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I am used in many cases to write a properties like

```
public string Data {get; private set; }
```

And usual I initialize them in the constructor
How can I give the Data some value ,not explicitly using constructor

Comment: You have to ask yourself, why do you still want to use *auto-properties*. Answer is, don't use them, use normal properties instead (which are typically expose private fields).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of Auto-implemented property use a backing field , Initialize that field with same value and then expose it through property like:

```
private string _Data = "Some Value";

public string Data
{
    get { return _Data; }
    private set { _Data = value; } //or remove it
}
```

Comment: I want to keep set to be private

Comment: @Yakov,  mark it as private or remove it all together.

Comment: @Selman22, Auto implemented properties can't be assigned a default value other than in constructor. But fields can be assigned a default value. So using an explicit field for normal property could achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a backing variable

```
private string _data = "foo";
public string Data {get {return _data;} private set {_data = value;}}
```

Or in C#6 you can write it like this

```
public string Data {get; private set; } = "foo";
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with an automatic proeprty.  If you have a backing field you can initialize it:

```
private string _Data = "some value";
public string Data {get {return _Data;} private set {_Data = value;} }
```

Answer (score 0):

C# 9.0 will provide new `init` accessor for this particular problem:

```
public class DataClass
{
    public string Data {get; init; }
}
```

Now you can use object initializer for your `DataClass` instead of constructor:

```
var d = new DataClass { Data = "newValue" };
```

More details [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/).